# Stop Skype from launching on startup? (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, skype, autostart

Skype keeps starting at startup without my permission. I don't want it to start minimised, there's already a solution for that, I want it **not to start**. But there isn't a single setting in Skype's options, and Skype is not in my startup applications.

**EDIT — as requested, a screenshot of the "session" tab in my Session & Startup settings:**

[image: Screenshot]

**And the weird output of that "grep -lir 'Skype' ~/.cache" command, giving me something about Kingsoft Office:**

```
/home/wolf/.cache/logrotate/status
/home/wolf/.cache/Kingsoft/wps/http/cache_c8034f79bfb82e94e16ff8ebebcfff38262f0359.cache
/home/wolf/.cache/Kingsoft/wps/http/cache_030f47fb47e37a138cb0973e152475a098eeee54.cache
```

Comment: Look in your `$HOME/.config/autostart` and if there is a file `skype.desktop` remove it. Close Skype and clean your session cache -> http://askubuntu.com/a/475284/265974 then restart.

Comment: Doesn't do it, there is no .desktop file for Skype there, or am I not seeing it? https://i.imgur.com/mhfRpVz.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent Skype from starting automatically on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/269080/how-can-i-prevent-skype-from-starting-automatically-on-boot)

Comment: Already saw that after posting, nothing out there works.

Comment: please add a screenshot from your "Session and Startup" -> "Session" settings [to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/489719/edit) and the output of `grep -lir 'Skype' ~/.cache`

Comment: Done. <!--(Just adding something stupid because I need more characters)-->

Comment: It looks like skype is not in your session cache... Are there any files in your `$HOME/.config/upstart` directory ?

Comment: Nothing. I've checked for hidden files too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent Skype from starting automatically on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269080/how-can-i-prevent-skype-from-starting-automatically-on-boot)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue ([and cross-posted this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269080/how-can-i-prevent-skype-from-starting-automatically-on-boot?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I was able to prevent it from starting automatically by removing `skypeforlinux.desktop` from `~/.config/autostart/`. I'm using lubuntu; the location of your autostart folder may vary. You can find by using:

```
$ locate skypeforlinux.desktop
```

You'll really only want to delete the copy in the directory called `autostart`, otherwise you won't be able to start the app from the icon.

I'm assuming that the next time you actually, intentionally run Skype (I hope, for the sake of your sanity, that this day is *far* in the future) that it will try to put that file back. In which case you might have to delete it again or scour Skype for the setting that will prevent that behavior.

Comment: Or better, change `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` to `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` in the file `~/.config/autostart/skypeforlinux.desktop`
EDIT: This applies, if you are using Gnome. It should be similar in other desktop environments.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions, from least to most invasive:

1. Exit all programs, then open `Sessie en opstart` and click `Sessie opslaan`. This ought to overwrite a session file named something like `~/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-$HOSTNAME:0` which may contain a reference to skype.
2. Manually edit any files named things like `xfce4-session-$HOSTNAME:0` in `~/.cache/sessions/`, changing any "skype" to "echo"
3. `sudo mv /usr/bin/skype /usr/bin/spyke` – it seems to run fine with a new name, but any calling scripts should fail to find it. You'll have to change/make a new .desktop file if you want clickability.

Comment: Ubuntu-MATE users [may also look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061954/479118)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get uninstall skypeforlinux`

I don't really need Skype as there are plenty of other options. If they feel the need to start it automatically on login, I feel the need to remove it from my system.