# Skype minify under Ubuntu-Mate

Tags: skype, mate, ubuntu-mate, startup-applications

I am running **Skype 8.20** under **Ubuntu-MATE 16.04**. It automatically starts after boot, but unlike defined in the settings: not minified / in-the-background, but as a regular window:

[image]

My question would be: **Is there a way to ensure it starts minified?**
(Perhaps by finding the “startup folder“ of sorts under Ubuntu and adding a minify flag there? Wherever that is, perhaps the switches there are only compatible for KDE, Gnome, whatever… )

Answer (score 0):

**Gotcha :-)** 
I apparently had forgotten, that I manually added Skype to ‚autostart‘ (learning that right now, trying to disable its autostart behaviour. Which neither works from the regular internal skype preferences... :)

[image]

And so, while we're at it: If you add skype to startup this way, you can also give it [command line switches](https://winaero.com/blog/skype-command-line-switches/), including...

```
    /minimized     Starts Skype minimized to the system tray.
```